# Does the Radeon HD 5450 support three displays?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I know that [ATI.com](http://ati.com) says that the Radeon HD 5450 supports three displays. My question is, how does it support three displays without DisplayPort? I see only VGA, HDMI, and DVI on 5450s.

Comment: One connected in each connector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is from the [AnandTech review](http://www.anandtech.com/video/showdoc.aspx?i=3734&p=2) of the AMD Radeon HD 5450:

> Finally, since the 5450 is a
>   low-profile card, we have yet another
>   variant in the port configuration. Our
>   sample card is equipped with 1 DVI
>   port and 1 DisplayPort directly on the
>   card, and a VGA port on the bracket
>   attached to the card via cable. The
>   5450 – like all other 5000-series
>   cards – supports 3-monitor Eyefinity,
>   so all 3 ports can be used at once,
>   although the VGA port is obviously
>   going to make it less desirable here.
>
> We should note that **only cards with a
>   DisplayPort will support Eyefinity**,
>   which means that if a vendor decides
>   to equip the card with an HDMI port
>   instead, they have to give up
>   Eyefinity to do so. We expect to see
>   some cards with HDMI for the HTPC
>   crowd, but at this point we don’t have
>   any idea as to how many there will be.
>   DVI-to-HDMI adaptors still work here,
>   so we may see vendors spend a bit more
>   money and go that route instead.

I've highlighted the part you'll be  interested in. Basically, without DisplayPort, there's no Eyefinity and, therefore, no 3 monitor support.

Comment: You're only partially right. The graphics cards will not support EyeFinity without DisplayPort, which means you don't get the fancy EyeFinity features like stretching the desktop across 3 screens as one large resolution. You can still run 3 displays as separate desktops though, just as you can use dual monitors on any video card with 2 DVI or a VGA and a DVI output.

Comment: Is what nhinkle says true? I really only want 3 displays on my desktop, so I will be happy with the HDMI, VGA and DVI.

Comment: The 5450 has displayport and therefore eyefinity and triple support. I'm using one right now. works fine in linux, YMMV for windows.

Comment: I plan to buy a 5450 card that has VGA, HDMI and DVI. Does that really mean that I can use 3 displays? This card does not have a DisplayPort.

Comment: @nhinkle are you sure i can run three displays with no eyefinity, but as three different displays with this card? thanks a lot

Comment: @José to my knowledge, the current state of affairs on ATI cards is as such: you can run three displays, but only up to 2 can be on DVI. The third (and any additional) must be displayport. However, for any multi-monitor setup, you have the choice to either do eyefinity and have one massive "desktop", or to just use it as three distinct displays.

Comment: @nhinkle: Can a card without DP run two monitors spanned as EyeFinity and the third without?

Comment: @SLaks to my knowledge, a card without DP can run at most 2 monitors in any configuration.

Comment: Sapphire 5450 1GB seem to have a built-in adapter (as recommended by AMD) which can display 3 monitors on it's VGA, HDMI and DVI output.
This is all confusing because the vendors make it very hard to find this details.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get a Radeon 5450 with a DisplayPort in order to do three monitors. They do  [make them](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814131345&cm_re=Radeon_5450-_-14-131-345-_-Product), but you have to be careful not to buy the wrong one.

Also, if you do not have to a DisplayPort monitor, you need to buy an [approved adapter](http://support.amd.com/us/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity-dongles.aspx) or the third port will most likely not work (it *sometimes* still does with other adapters).